# Popover in Lightning Web Component (LWC)

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, popover

I am trying to implement a popover in Salesforce LWC. I am able to get it work but only issue is the popover is not actually coming above the body like a modal. You can see the sample [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/NdN6X9pFk/1/edit). As you see when a radio button is clicked I want to show a help popover but without taking height of the entire row/div. Is this something possible? Appreciate any inputs !! Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check [Playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/NdN6X9pFk/3/edit)

[image]

You need to use position `relative` for parent and position `absolute` for child so that the child is placed in view-port according to position of parent. You should also use any 2 properties from `left,top,right,bottom` on child to position it correctly. Below is what you can do:

Make the parent relative using `slds-is-relative`:

```
<div class="slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12 slds-float_right ">
    <section if:true={opt.checked} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then, adjust the position of child element through css:

```
.slds-popover.slds-nubbin_left{
    position: absolute;
    left:0rem;
    top:-1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!! :)