# Object hover not displaying as expected for LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I referred this question to display object hover in my LWC. [LWC: How do I display “out of box” object hover?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257221/lwc-how-do-i-display-out-of-box-object-hover)

Instead of popup, I get an additional LWC on the same page. It appears on `mouseover` and disappers on `mouseout`. Please guide me as to why the popup is not appearing. Thanks!

[image: Additional LWC]

### Code

**Apex Class**

```java
public with sharing class PopupData {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccounts(){
        List<Account> acc = new List<Account>();
        acc = [select Id, Name, Master_Customer_ID__c from Account Limit 5];
        return acc;
    }
}
```

**Main LWC**

```html
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Name">Name</div>
                </th>
                <th class="slds-cell-buffer_right" scope="col">
                    <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Age">MDM ID</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <template if:true={bears.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template  for:each={bears.data} for:item="bear" for:index="index">

                    <tr class={assignClass} key={bear.Id} data-rangerid={bear.Id} onmouseout={hideData} onmouseover={showData}>

                        <td data-label="Bear Name" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                            <div class=slds-truncate title="Bear Name">{bear.Name}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td data-label="Bear Age" class="slds-cell-buffer_right">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Bear Age">{bear.Master_Customer_ID__c}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </template>
                </div>
        </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <c-box-popover topmargin={top} leftmargin={left} myranger={ranger}></c-box-popover>

</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import searchBears from '@salesforce/apex/PopupData.getAccounts';

export default class SelectPicklist extends LightningElement() {
  @track searchTerm = '';
    @track bears;
    @track ranger;
    @track left;
    @track top;

    @wire(searchBears)
    loadBears(result) {
        this.bears = result;
    }
    showData(event){
        this.ranger = event.currentTarget.dataset.rangerid;
        this.left = event.clientX;
        this.top=event.clientY;
    }
    hideData(event){
        this.ranger = "";
    }
    get assignClass() { 
        return this.active ? '' : 'slds-hint-parent';
  }
}
```

**Popup LWC**

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <template if:true={ranger} >
            <lightning-record-view-form
                    record-id={ranger}
                    object-api-name="Account">
                <div class="potato slds-box" style={boxClass}>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
                    </lightning-output-field>
                    <lightning-output-field field-name="Master_Customer_ID__c">
                    </lightning-output-field>
                    </div>
            </lightning-record-view-form>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class BoxPopover extends LightningElement {
    @track ranger;
    @track top = 50;
    @track left = 50;

    @api
    get myranger(){
        return this.ranger;
    }

    set myranger(value) {
        this.ranger = value;
    }

    @api
    get topmargin(){
        return this.top;
    }

    set topmargin(value) {
        this.top = value;
    }

    @api
    get leftmargin(){
        return this.left;
    }

    set leftmargin(value) {
        this.left = value;
    }

    get boxClass() { 
        return 'background-color:white; top:${this.top - 280}px; left:${this.left}px';
      }
}
```

Comment: check it [Popover in Lightning Web Component (LWC)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274343/popover-in-lightning-web-component-lwc)

Comment: @sanketkumar They have used the same LWC for Popup whereas I have different LWC for Popup (as child).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is need to use position absolute for child so that the child is placed in view-port according to position of parent.

Make the following changes in **Popup LWC**

***Javascript***

```js
get boxClass() { 
        return `position: absolute; background-color:white; top:${this.top - 280}px; left:${this.left}px`;
}
```

***HTML***

```html
<div class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left potato slds-box" style={boxClass}>
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Name">
          </lightning-output-field>
          <lightning-output-field field-name="Master_Customer_ID__c">
    </lightning-output-field>
</div>
```