# How to put a over in the LWC that is displayed on the overing of the mouse on the link

Tags: javascript, community, lightning-web-components, html, ui

I need to put an event in my lightning Web component "onmouseover" whenever user bring the mouse over thetest i need to display a badge full of message, currently it is not coming as expected.
kindly help on this.
below is the code.

```
 <div class="slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12 slds-float_right ">
    <section if:true={opt.checked} class="slds-popover slds-nubbin_left" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-popover__body">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then, adjust the position of child element through css:

```
.slds-popover.slds-nubbin_left{
    position: absolute;
    left:0rem;
    top:-1.3rem;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please could you take a minute to read [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/315550/edit) your question with more complete information. For me, what you have here doesn't provide enough of your LWC component's detail in order to help you.

Comment: A similar question was asked here- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/274343/popover-in-lightning-web-component-lwc